# mysql replication status using mysqlrplshow

Tags: mysql

I have configured the mysql replication using the below command,

```
[root@master ~]# mysqlreplicate --master=root:De@123@master.server.com:3306 --slave=root:De@123@slave.server.com:3306 --rpl-user=mysqlreplica:Dev123 --start-from-beginning -vvv
WARNING: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
# master on master.server.com: ... connected.
# slave on slave.server.com: ... connected.
# master id = 1
#  slave id = 2
# master uuid = ecef97ff-1a92-11e7-9807-0021f6f0406f
#  slave uuid = 3d043f16-1a93-11e7-95c0-0021f6f0406e
# Checking InnoDB statistics for type and version conflicts.
# Checking storage engines...
# Checking for binary logging on master...
# Setting up replication...
# Granting replication access to replication user...
# Connecting slave to master...
# CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST = 'master.server.com', MASTER_USER = 'mysqlreplica', MASTER_PASSWORD = 'Dev123', MASTER_PORT = 3306, MASTER_AUTO_POSITION=1
# Starting slave from the beginning...
# IO status: Waiting for master to send event
# IO thread running: Yes
# IO error: None
# SQL thread running: Yes
# SQL error: None
# ...done.
```

After this what ever transcation am doing on Master server, everything properly replicating to Slave server.

But when I tried to discover the slaves using mysqlrplshow which doesn't working properly.

```
[root@master ~]# mysqlrplshow -r -p --master=root:De@123@master.server.com --discover-slaves-login=root:De@123 -vvv
WARNING: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
# master on master.server.com: ... connected.
# Finding slaves for master: master.server.com:3306

WARNING: Cannot connect to some slaves:
 - master.server.com:3306: Server 'master.server.com:3306' is not acting as a slave (slave status is empty).

# Replication Topology Graph
No slaves found.
```

Am using the root account password for both Master and Salve with mysqlrplshow. Not sure what am missing here.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind! Its fixed, looks like I mentioned report host as master server on both Master and Slave my.cnf. I have changed this to slave host name and its fixed now.